# What are the benefits of merging a unit?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

While playing the game, I've found myself down to the option of unit merging, and wondered what does that imply?

Why should I merge units?

What are the benefits of doing it?

Comment: Try to always make your question body in question format.  Even when self-answering.

Comment: As for the three downvoters, please, feel invited to suggest improvements on the post. As the StackExchange itself suggest: try leaving a comment before downvoting.

Comment: The downvotes are likely because instant self answers aren't very popular around these parts. It's often seen as point fishing. That's my guess anyway.

Comment: Got it. I decided to post it because just yesterday, after playing more than 4 months, I learned that skills are also passed on during the merge process. I looked up on the web to find proofs, did some tests myself and found relevant. I'd never ask this question prior to knowing that o didn't know all the points :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There 3 situations with different outcomes:

**Merging two units of same potential (4* into 4*, becomes 4*+1)**

- SP gain (40 for 3*, 80 for 4*, and 120 for 5*)
- Inherited skills are passed on, learned and unlearned both, including weapons
- 2 points of stats gain
- You get to chose the hero with the best IV to keep, improving him/her even further
- Feather discount for increasing potential (150 for 3*, 300 for 4*)

The optimal out of the three options, as you are literally getting every benefit possible from ally merging.

**Merging a higher potential into a lower potential unit (5* into 4*, becomes 4*+1)**

- SP gain (40 for 3*, 80 for 4*, and 120 for 5*)
- Inherited skills are passed on, learned and unlearned both, including weapons
- 2 points of stats gain
- You get to chose the hero with the best IV to keep, improving him/her even further
- Feather discount for increasing potential (150 for 3*, 300 for 4*)

Keep in mind that the hero *potential will not increase*, therefore it will still have the same maximum status as a 4* hero. A 5* hero is equivalent to its 4*+5 version.

**Merging a lower potential into a higher potential unit (3* into 4*, staying 4*)**

- SP gain (40 for 3*, 80 for 4*, and 120 for 5*)
- Inherited skills are passed on, learned and unlearned both, including weapons

May be useful for players who were investing in a unit and got a version with higher potential afterwards. Also, it may come in handy if you need that extra SP to save some of your time.

Comment: It's been a while since I played, but doesn't merging a 4* into a 5* do nothing other than SP gain and Inherited skills?  Currently your answer has the 5* downgrading to a 4* (I imagine that to be a typo)  It might also be worth mentioning that the +X to a character are lost on raising potential so giving +1s to 4* units is a bad idea if you think you might ever bump them up to 5*

Comment: Oops, typo! Tks!